# Construct std::map with non-copyable value type using initializer list constructor

Tags: c++

Is there a way to construct a std::map with a non-copyable value type using the initializer list constructor?

See the following example

```cpp
#include <memory>
#include <map>

int main()
{
  std::map<int, int*> int_ptr{{1, nullptr}}; // compiles
  // std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<int>> unique_ptr_int{{1, std::unique_ptr<int>()}}; // Doesn't compile
}
```

**Note: I'm specifically asking if this can be done with the intializer list constructor. I know I can construct the map using a different constructor and add the elements, but I would like to know if the use of this constructor is possible and how to do it, maybe using std::piecewise_construct or something like that.**

Answer (score 0):

I guess the easiest thing to do is to put smart pointers inside your map, this way the object is never copied.

```
std::map<int,std::shared_ptr<myobj>> myobj_Map;
```

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. The question is whether or not I can use the initializer list constructor in this particular case where the value type is non-copyable, and how to do it if it's possible.